# Кодировка в консоли PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, utf-8

Русские символы выводятся кракозябрами. Команда "chcp 65001" не помогла. Как настроить кодировку?

Comment: А сам файл в кодировке utf-8? или это везде?

Comment: @RakzinRoman, какой файл?
Вот что получается: http://automated-testing.info/uploads/default/972/3ee8c2a66d24d297.png